# Autofollow a record in Chater

Tags: apex, chatter

I am new to APEX, and I am trying to write a class that would set a user to autofollow a record in Chatter. I have a user lookup field on a custom object, and whenever that field is updated or populated, then that user should autofollow the record. When the lookup field is updated with a new user, then that new user should replace the old autofollow user. I did use some references, and wrote the code bellow, but that code only keeps adding new users to the autofollow list. Could someone help me update my code? I was able to write a trigger for this, but would like to manage the logic via a class.

```
public static void DevOwnerChatSub(list <Story__c> story){

        List<EntitySubscription> subscription = new List <EntitySubscription>();
        for (Story__c str:story) {
            if(str.Owner__c != NULL){
                subscription.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentID = str.Id,SubscriberId = str.Owner__c));
            }
        }
        try{
            Database.insert(subscription);
        }
        catch (DMLException dmlEx){
            if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0)==statusCode.Duplicate_Value) {
                System.Debug('DevOwnerChatSub: subscription already exists');
            } else{
                throw dmlEx;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have write a logic to pass `oldMap` and `newMap` from the Story trigger.

Need to prepare 2 lists based record availability. If previous owner exists then it will move into updateSubscription list, otherwise it will move into newSubscription list.

Finally, do insert and update operations on those lists.

```
public static void DsaevOwnerChatSub(Map<Id,Story__c> oldStoryMap, Map<Id,Story__c> newStoryMap)
{

    List<EntitySubscription> newSubscription = new List <EntitySubscription>();
    List<EntitySubscription> updateSubscription = new List <EntitySubscription>();

    for(Id strId:newStoryMap.keySet())
    {
        Story__c newObject = (Story__c) newStoryMap.get(strId);
        if(newObject.Owner__c != null)
        {
            Story__c oldObject = (Story__c)oldStoryMap.get(strId);                    
            if((oldObject.Owner__c != newObject.Owner__c) && (oldObject.Owner__c !=null))
            {
                //consider this an update to the owner
                newObject.SubscriberId = newObject.Owner__c;
                updateSubscription.add(newObject);
            }
            else if (oldObject.Owner__c !=null)
            {
                //consider this as new owner
                newSubscription.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentID = newObject.Id,SubscriberId = newObject.Owner__c));
            }
        }
    }

    try{
        Database.insert(newSubscription);
        Database.update(updateSubscription);
    }
    catch (DMLException dmlEx){
        if (dmlEx.getDmlType(0)==statusCode.Duplicate_Value) {
            System.Debug('DevOwnerChatSub: subscription already exists');
        } else{
            throw dmlEx;
        }
    }

}
```

*Note: I have tried to give you a logic to insert or update the record. I have not complied or executed this code*

Comment: Thank you so much Santanu. I will test it out. I really appreciate it !!!

Comment: I get an error on line "Try {" ,  mismatched input 'try' expecting RCURLY. I am trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: can you take my code once again

Comment: Hmm, I am getting an error on the SubscriberId field. IT says invalid field SubscriberId for SObject Story__c. Trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: check, owner Id is properly getting assigned or not

Comment: I think that is because the subscriberid field does not exist on the Story object, as we are referencing that object.

Comment: Hi Santanu, I think I found the issue. I am referencing SubscriberId, but that field does not exist on the Story__c object. That is why I need create a new EntitySubcription and define the Subscriber ID in it. 
Like:EntitySubscription stEntity = new EntitySubscription();
  stEntity.ParentId = strId.Id;
  stEntity.SubscriberId = strId.Owner__c;

I am just not sure how I can enter that in my the code I have above. Do you think you can help me. Sorry, I am very new to Apex.

Comment: you can first accept this ans and post a new question so that other members can also look into this and respond accordingly